# AS3. How to make good collision between hero's and enemy's animations?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, actionscript, collision-detection, collision

What is best way to make collision between player and enemy?

In stay animation my Player's width is 30px, in walking animation 40px and in attack1 animation width 60px.

For now I use code:

```
if (Enemy.hitTestObject(Hero))
            {
    Enemy.gotoAndStop("attack1");
    }
```

If Enemy touch Hero (main character) starts attack animation. But here is problem that if player's current state is in attack position Enemy stay so far ant trying to hit.

I need to make something like that enemy always checked player's "stay" animations width, not current animation. Or maybe you could suggest better collision tips? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
So If I have simple attack1, I need to call `enterFrameHandler()` in this function? And this will check if Hero have collision with Enemy? Or Where I need to use this function?

```
if (attack1)
{
            enterFrameHandler();
    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack1");

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is how I declare enemy:

```
public var Enemy:Priesas = new Priesas; //Priesas is instance name of Enemy
```

Hero is choosing template by clicking buttons:

```
public function selectHero(what:int):void {
    // this is called with correct "what", design yourself. I use array index
    var whatHero:Class = heroes[what]; // get selected hero symbol
    if (Hero && Hero.parent) Hero.parent.removeChild(Hero);
    // clean up previous hero. Drop listeners here, if any
    Hero = new whatHero(); // get new hero
    // process as usual, don't forget to "addChild(Hero)" somewhere
    create_hero();
}

    function choosePlayer(event:MouseEvent):void {
        selectHero(0);
        start(event);
        }

     function create_hero()
     {
        addChild(Hero);
     }
```

So declared variables are: Hero and Enemy

**UPDATE 3**

For now I got following errors:

```
1120: Access of undefined property enemyClipBmpData.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Point.
1120: Access of undefined property heroClipBmpData.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method GlowFilter.
```

Here is how my code looks like now (I know about uppercase by creating vars, but for now I need to use like this)

```
    public function Script()
    {

        btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
        btn_credits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, choosePlayer);
        btn_control.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, key_down);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, key_up);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true); //here added line

    }

    function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        Hero.x = mouseX;
        Hero.y = mouseY;

        if(enemyClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(Enemy.x, Enemy.y),
                                255,
                                heroClipBmpData,
                                new Point(Hero.x, Hero.y),
                                255

                          ))
        {
            trace("hit");
            Enemy.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
        }
        else
        {
            Enemy.filters = [];
        }
    }

function create_enemy()
        {
            addChild(Enemy);
            var enemyRect:Rectangle = Enemy.getBounds(this);
            var enemyClipBmpData = new BitmapData(enemyRect.width, enemyRect.height, true, 0);
            enemyClipBmpData.draw(Enemy);
            Enemy.x = 10;
            Enemy.y = 420;
        }

     function create_hero()
    {

        addChild(Hero);
        var heroRect:Rectangle = Hero.getBounds(this);
        var heroClipBmpData = new BitmapData(heroRect.width, heroRect.height, true, 0);
        heroClipBmpData.draw(Hero);
        Hero.gotoAndStop("stay");
        Hero.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
}
```

Comment: One solution could be to add a invisible block over your character that you want to use for collisions, and test against that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could try using BitmapData.hitTest, something like:

```
//using your instance name (just using lower case for the instance name)
var enemy:Priesas = new Priesas();
enemy.x = enemy.y = 300;
addChild(enemy);

var enemyRect:Rectangle = enemy.getBounds(this);
var enemyClipBmpData = new BitmapData(enemyRect.width, enemyRect.height, true, 0);
enemyClipBmpData.draw(enemy);

//using your instance name (just using lower case for the instance name)
var hero:Sprite = new Hero();
addChild(hero);

var heroRect:Rectangle = hero.getBounds(this);
var heroClipBmpData = new BitmapData(heroRect.width, heroRect.height, true, 0);
heroClipBmpData.draw(hero);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler, false, 0, true);

function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    hero.x = mouseX;
    hero.y = mouseY;

    if(enemyClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(enemy.x, enemy.y),
                            255,
                            heroClipBmpData,
                            new Point(hero.x, hero.y),
                            255

                      ))
    {
        trace("hit");
        enemy.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
    }
    else
    {
        enemy.filters = [];
    }
}
```

Based on the documentation:

```
public function hitTest(firstPoint:Point, firstAlphaThreshold:uint, secondObject:Object, secondBitmapDataPoint:Point = null, secondAlphaThreshold:uint = 1):Boolean
```

Performs pixel-level hit detection between one bitmap image and a point, rectangle, or other bitmap image. A hit is defined as an overlap of a point or rectangle over an opaque pixel, or two overlapping opaque pixels. No stretching, rotation, or other transformation of either object is considered when the hit test is performed.

If an image is an opaque image, it is considered a fully opaque rectangle for this method. Both images must be transparent images to perform pixel-level hit testing that considers transparency. When you are testing two transparent images, the alpha threshold parameters control what alpha channel values, from 0 to 255, are considered opaque.

**Parameters**

- **firstPoint:Point** — A position of the upper-left corner of the BitmapData image in an arbitrary coordinate space. The same coordinate space is used in defining the secondBitmapPoint parameter.
- **firstAlphaThreshold:uint** — The smallest alpha channel value that is considered opaque for this hit test.
- **secondObject:Object** — A Rectangle, Point, Bitmap, or BitmapData object.
- **secondBitmapDataPoint:Point** (default = null) — A point that defines a pixel location in the second BitmapData object. Use this parameter only when the value of secondObject is a BitmapData object.
- **secondAlphaThreshold:uint** (default = 1) — The smallest alpha channel value that is considered opaque in the second BitmapData object. Use this parameter only when the value of secondObject is a BitmapData object and both BitmapData objects are transparent.

**Returns**

Boolean — A value of true if a hit occurs; otherwise, false.

**Throws**

ArgumentError — The secondObject parameter is not a Point, Rectangle, Bitmap, or BitmapData object.

TypeError — The firstPoint is null.

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you explain me code a little bit? How It works?

Comment: When I try this I got errors: `1120: Access of undefined property blueClip.`, `1120: Access of undefined property redClip.`, `1120: Access of undefined property redClipBmpData.`

Comment: I just added more details about the documentation of the method, so, will be possible to understand.
You you replace redClip and blueClip for your instance names, I just added it as example.

Comment: Thank you for help! I updated my question with problem which I misunderstand now.

Comment: No, the example I sent you, will be to detect the collision between Hero and Enemy (you replace the original hitTestObject)

Comment: Ah now I got It, but what I need to use now instead of `if (Enemy.hitTestObject(Hero))`?

Comment: could you edit your answer and add the code where you declare those objects Enemy and Hero?

Comment: Check my edited answer (using Hero and Enemy) instance names. I just replaced to lower case, because the first letter using Upper case, should be used just for a Class name (following code conventions)

Comment: I updated my question with following errors which I got now and code how my code looks like for now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46164/discussion-between-gpeart-and-infinity)